# WindowsApps folder still contains large folders from deleted Microsoft Applications

Tags: windows-10

Win10 > Program Files > WindowsApps

There are a lot of Windows Apps that come pre-installed on Win10, such as XBOX app, Microsoft Notes.  I uninstalled these apps and programs.  But the WindowsApps folder still contains huge directories relating to these programs.

Is there anyway to safely remove all these leftover files + folders.  Win10 does not give me permission to read/modify the folder.  I can change the owner, but i don't want to cause issues.

Comment: Can you manually give yourself the required permissions: yes... is it recommended to modify anything in the `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps` directory: no.  Try running Disk Cleanup and tick the box for system files.  AFAIK, manually removing Windows Apps via Powershell should remove their constituent files and directories.  If leftovers are specific to Microsoft apps only, it may be there are other Microsoft apps sharing access to those files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Uninstalling an app from your user account will not remove the app from the disk.
It will remain there so that Windows can re-create the built-in apps for new
user accounts when they are created and log on.
Therefore, these apps, called staged or provisioned, continue to take disk space even
though they seem to be uninstalled.

To remove provisioned apps you have to use in an elevated PowerShell session the
`remove-AppxProvisionedPackage` command, like this:

```
remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -package Microsoft.BingTravel_1.2.0.145_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe -online
```

This command removes the Bing Travel package from all locations,
including the `WindowsApps` folder and the Start menu.
To re-install later, go to the Windows Store, My library section.

Comment: How to clear all uninstalled apps?

Comment: It doesn't seem to delete the files. Should it work if I happened to remove the app first using `Remove-AppxPackage`?

Comment: Please ask this in a separate post, giving full details about the package and the left-over files.

Answer (score 1):

you could uninstall this provisioned cache use [dism++.exe](https://github.com/Chuyu-Team/Dism-Multi-language)：

[image: DISM++ screenshot]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).