# Windows apps old versions are not removed from hard

Tags: windows-10, installation, uninstall

I found that upgrading new windows app does not remove the old versions. So when I navigate to `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` there are mulity versions of some apps.
Is there any way to remove them **automatically**? ( I found a manual approach at [WindowsApps folder still contains large folders from deleted Microsoft Applications](https://superuser.com/questions/1517457/windowsapps-folder-still-contains-large-folders-from-deleted-microsoft-applicati))

For example you can see there are three versions of `windowscommunicationsapp`

[image]

Comment: Hello @AlirezaFattahi . Which manual approach worked for you? I didn't find anything useful in the linked question/answer (`Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage` doesn't work for old versions, at least for me). Just like you, I would love to learn how to perform the cleanup automatically. In the meantime I will settle for manual method that works. Help please?

Comment: it was long a go but i think https://superuser.com/a/1517474/263669 helped me