# How do I delete apps being installed by the Microsoft Store

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-store

I have some kind of issue with the Xbox Gamepass app on PC. Two games I tried installing now appear forever as downloading, and the Xbox app only gives the error code 0x000000. Microsoft's help page doesn't prove helpful for me. Now, I've been stuck with these two games being stuck in installed status for over a week now:

[image]

Right click uninstalling these apps will remove them until the next restart of my computer, at which point they appear again. Short of a reformat, how can I permanently delete these two games from being stuck in installed status?

Edit:

In response to comments, Gaming Services looks like this:

[image]

The downloads screen looks like this:

[image]

And clicking on the "See Details" buttons shows the same popup for all 3 apps:

[image]

Comment: I would try performing a Reset on the Microsoft Store from within Settings.  I would also try running `wsreset.exe`.  Can you provide a screenshot of `start ms-windows-store://pdp/?productid=9MWPM2CQNLHN` (It's a PowerShell command) You can also try repairing `gaming services`

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1517457/windowsapps-folder-still-contains-large-folders-from-deleted-microsoft-applicati) help solve the problem?

Comment: `Gaming Services` is located at `Settings -> Apps & Features` and you should go to -Advanced Options and perform a Reset

Comment: Thanks for the help @Ramhound , sadly none of those tips helped. I updated the question with screenshots.

Comment: So your issue is that Gaming Services is broken.  [This](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/all/xbox-game-pass-pc-i-cant-install-games/d752f08e-4468-4464-be9a-d4350fc4dea7?page=3) outlines a solution that involves removing Gaming Services and a couple registry keys, then has you reinstall Gaming Services.  I hope you are running 21H1.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound, I followed that guide but still have the same issue. GS refuses to install?

Comment: Try simply signing out of your Microsoft Account and back into your Microsoft Account within Windows Store.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound, but none of your solutions helped. The only way that helped me out was by nuking the entire Microsoft store from my PC with the command Get-AppxPackage *windowsstore* | Remove-AppxPackage